# Escaping single quote creating unrequired "\" in the HTML page

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have to show the name of an employee on an HTML page and on mouse over the employee name again, as shown below.

[image]

There is a problem when employee name contains single quote in
innerHTML value which is throwing the JavaScript error

```
missing ) after argument list
At line: 1
```

Using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript` solves the JavaScript error but the actual HTML renderer retains the `"\"` before the single quote. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Why not to use double quotes instead? :)

Comment: Post the code used to generate this HTML and we'll help you fix/improve that code.

Comment: double quotes!! Employee name is obtained from DB and flushed on HTML page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply can't use the same text in HTML and in JavaScript. They are different languages with different escaping needs.

Use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()` for HTML and `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript()` for JavaScript.

**Edit**: yes, show us the code that's generating the HTML. Perhaps you don't need to escape the text for HTML yourself if it's being done by someone else's code.